# Where does Google's Drive API store downloaded files?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm attempting to download a file from Google Drive using Python, and I'm not sure where the file is being stored.

Following the example here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#python

Code:

```
def DownloadGoogleFile(id: int):
    file = str(id) + '.txt'
    creds = GetGoogleCredentials()
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    FileSearch = service.files().list(q="name='{0}'".format(file), fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    FoundFiles = FileSearch.get('files', [])
    if FoundFiles:
        FileID = FoundFiles[0]['id']
        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=FileID)
        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
    else:
        output = 'No file found'
```

I'm getting output of `Download 100%` but that's it. I can't find the file anywhere. I was thinking it'd be in the same directory as the python file, but there isn't anything there. I also though it may need to be `fh=io.FileIO(file)` as a way to specify where I want to save the file, but I'm getting a 'no file exists' error when doing that so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Following the example from the docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.MediaIoBaseDownload-class.html), you should be able to just replace

```
fh = io.BytesIO()
```

With

```
fh = io.FileIO('filename.extension', mode='wb')
```

`io.BytesIO()` is an in memory file-like object and is not written to disk

Comment: Thank you! That does save the file like I needed. I'll mark it as the answer as soon as I can.